# Pass in entity link as @RequestParam to @RepositoryRestController method

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have inside a `@RepositoryRestController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/salesReport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> get(
            @RequestParam(value = "customer", required = false) Resource<Organization> customer,
            @RequestParam(value = "supplier", required = false) Organization supplier,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) Date startDate,
            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyyy") @RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = false) Date endDate,
            Pageable pageable
    ) { ...
```

The Organization type request params here, I would like to pass in as SDR style uris. When I pass in Long ids, it works fine and gets converted to entity object automatically. But when I pass in uri, I get:

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.hateoas.Resource]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.hateoas.Resource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

Does anyone know if Spring actually supports automatically converting uris to entity objects in a `@RepositoryRestController` and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsController {

    @Autoware
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}/report/{data}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getReport(@PathVariable("id") Product product, @PathVariable("date") Date date) {
        // some checks...
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.makeReport(product, date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I have like 6-7 parameters and they are all optional (for filtering). So this approach doesn't really help.

Comment: Also I pass these params encoded in the url not in the body anyway.